# How can I make Perl store integers as numbers instead of strings?

Tags: perl, perlguts

I'm parsing many numbers from a text file into hash entries consisting of a key and corresponding reference to array of values. Using Devel::Peek and Devel::Size I noticed that the string representation of the numbers is stored along in this data structure, which wastes memory. How can I rid the memory of these string representations (in other words, how can I turn a PVIV into an IV)?

Comment: Are you having a problem with memory usage? If so, there might be other strategies to look at first before worrying about internal storage representations.

Comment: uh, this is the least of Perl's "memory waste". You probably think a sub's scalars get deallocated when the sub is exited, don't you?

Comment: @AndyLester What strategies would that be? I have input files that can be several GB in size and arrange data from multiple input files into CSVs

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I would have thought so, or at least marked for garbage collection. What constraints keep Perl from doing that?

Comment: @rubystallion, To speed things up. Scalars can contain up to three memory blocks. Allocating and deallocating every time a sub is called would slow things down.

Comment: See also [Packed::Array](https://metacpan.org/pod/Packed::Array). Another alternative that could save memory would be using [pack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)

Comment: Maybe also PDL?

Comment: @rubystallion It's hard to say what to suggest without knowing anything about what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you're trying to save memory at this level, Perl is probably not the tool for you. Perl wantonly "wastes" memory when it provides a speed benefit.

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   use Devel::Size qw( size );

   sub f {
      my $x;
      say size($x);
      $x = "x" x 100;
      say size($x);
   }

   f() for 1..2;
'
24
134
134
134
```

---

Both `0+$scalar` and `int($scalar)` return a scalar of type `SVt_IV` or `SVt_NV`. Either of these will do.

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   use Devel::Size qw( size );
   my $x = 1234567890;
   my $y = "1234567890";
   say size($x);
   say size($y);
   say size($0+$y);
   say size(int($y));
'
24
44
24
24
```

---

It's not possible to downgrade an existing scalar, but you could replace it through "aliasing".

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   use experimental qw( refaliasing );
   use Devel::Size qw( size );
   my $x = 1234567890;
   my $y = "1234567890";
   say size($x);
   say size($y);
   \$y = \(0+$y);
   say size($y);
'
24
44
24
```

Comment: I thought `undef $s;` (as opposed to `$s = undef;`) would downgrade, but it doesn't.

Comment: Do you know why we get size == 24 out of number? A C int type is typically only 4 bytes, so what are the 20 extra bytes used for? E.g.: `perl -MDevel::Size=size -E '$k = 1; say size $k'`

Comment: @HåkonHægland A 64-bit int would be 8 bytes. But this isn't an `int`; this is a scalar. And a scalar needs to contain info about the type of the values or contains. Also, there are many types of scalars (to save memory), and Perl needs to be able to upgrade from one type to another without invalidating pointers to the scalar. This is done by having a head which contains a pointer to an upgradeable body. So that's three ints/pointers, or 24 bytes. https://st.aticpan.org/source/RURBAN/illguts-0.49/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Apply the "numify operator" `0+` to them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Devel::Peek;

# PVIVs (strings that were used in a numeric context)
my @values = grep 0+$_, qw/123 234/;
my %hash = ( "key" => [ @values ] );
Dump \%hash;
# make them just IVs
%hash = ( "key" => [ map 0+$_, @values ] );
Dump \%hash;
```

Output:

```
SV = IV(0x7fcaf401d9d0) at 0x7fcaf401d9e0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x7fcaf4025290
  SV = PVHV(0x7fcaf400ac60) at 0x7fcaf4025290
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (SHAREKEYS)
    ARRAY = 0x7fcaf3c1ad00  (0:7, 1:1)
    hash quality = 100.0%
    KEYS = 1
    FILL = 1
    MAX = 7
    Elt "key" HASH = 0x11e2db55
    SV = IV(0x7fcaf401d928) at 0x7fcaf401d938
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (ROK)
      RV = 0x7fcaf401d908
      SV = PVAV(0x7fcaf4005c58) at 0x7fcaf401d908
        REFCNT = 1
        FLAGS = ()
        ARRAY = 0x7fcaf3c04550
        FILL = 1
        MAX = 1
        FLAGS = (REAL)
        Elt No. 0
        SV = PVIV(0x7fcaf4021080) at 0x7fcaf401d920
          REFCNT = 1
          FLAGS = (IOK,POK,IsCOW,pIOK,pPOK)
          IV = 123
          PV = 0x7fcaf3c04900 "123"\0
          CUR = 3
          LEN = 10
          COW_REFCNT = 2
        Elt No. 1
        SV = PVIV(0x7fcaf4021098) at 0x7fcaf401d950
          REFCNT = 1
          FLAGS = (IOK,POK,IsCOW,pIOK,pPOK)
          IV = 234
          PV = 0x7fcaf3c0e2b0 "234"\0
          CUR = 3
          LEN = 10
          COW_REFCNT = 2
SV = IV(0x7fcaf401d9d0) at 0x7fcaf401d9e0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x7fcaf4025290
  SV = PVHV(0x7fcaf400ac60) at 0x7fcaf4025290
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (SHAREKEYS)
    ARRAY = 0x7fcaf3c1ad00  (0:7, 1:1)
    hash quality = 100.0%
    KEYS = 1
    FILL = 1
    MAX = 7
    Elt "key" HASH = 0x11e2db55
    SV = IV(0x7fcaf40252f8) at 0x7fcaf4025308
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (ROK)
      RV = 0x7fcaf401d9f8
      SV = PVAV(0x7fcaf4005ca8) at 0x7fcaf401d9f8
        REFCNT = 1
        FLAGS = ()
        ARRAY = 0x7fcaf3c0c6d0
        FILL = 1
        MAX = 1
        FLAGS = (REAL)
        Elt No. 0
        SV = IV(0x7fcaf401da78) at 0x7fcaf401da88
          REFCNT = 1
          FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
          IV = 123
        Elt No. 1
        SV = IV(0x7fcaf401da60) at 0x7fcaf401da70
          REFCNT = 1
          FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
          IV = 234
```

Comment: Is that maybe dependent on the interpreter version? I tried your approach before posting on v5.26.1 with the command `perl -MDevel::Peek -MDevel::Size=size -E '$a="1234567890";$b=1234567890;$a=0+$a;say size($a);say size($b);Dump($a);Dump($b)'` and got the output (sorry that this doesn't format correctly)

    48
    24
    SV = PVIV(0x55555597ce20) at 0x5555559811e8
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
      IV = 1234567890
      PV = 0
    SV = IV(0x555555981130) at 0x555555981140
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
      IV = 1234567890

Comment: @rubystallion, That's because you copied the newly created `SVt_IV` scalar created by `0+$a` into the existing `SVt_PVIV` scalar.